# Binary Search using start < end vs. using start <= end

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search

In binary search, we usually have low and high variables and typically there is a while loop that tests if low <= high, as shown in this code (from Wikipedia):

```
int SortedArray[max] = {....}

int BinarySearch (int key)
{
    int start = 0;
    int end = max - 1;
    int mid;
    while (start <= end)
    {
        mid = (start + end) / 2;
        if (key == a[mid])
            return mid;
        else if (key < a[mid])
            end = mid - 1;
        else start = mid + 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

When learning binary search, I was always taught the start <= end approach, but when seeing other implementations, I've seen a lot of people do while(start < end).

Is there an advantage to one versus the other? In my own native implementations, I do the <= approach but when I switch it out for <, the search fails.

Is there a rule of thumb for using one versus the other?

Comment: can we see your implementation and/or the example?

Comment: Post your code and we'll tell you why it fails. In a good implementation it's, at most, a tiny implementation detail and will make no practical difference.

Comment: I think this question is A) very clear, we don't need any examples to understand it, B) very useful because the Binary Search while(start < end) vs. while(start <= end) loop is very confusing

Answer (score 13, accepted):

even if your question is probably not super clear, I could infer you are talking about this kind of implementation of the binary search (here in C, from Wikipedia):

```
int SortedArray[max] = {....}

int BinarySearch (int key)
{
    int start = 0;
    int end = max - 1;
    int mid;
    while (start <= end)
    {
        mid = (start + end) / 2;
        if (key == a[mid])
            return mid;
        else if (key < a[mid])
            end = mid - 1;
        else start = mid + 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

If you replace `start <= end` by `start < end`, there will be cases where your algorithm will not give the good answer.

Let's think about two cases.

1 - You would like to search 1 in the list `[1]`. In that case, `start = 0, end = 0` and the algorithm would return -1 if you change the loop condition.

2 - You would like to search 2 in the list `[1, 2]`. In that case, start = 0, end = 1. The algorithm will set `mid = (0+1)/2=0` in C. Thus `arr[mid] < key`. It will make `start = 1, end = 1`. Again, if you stop the loop here, the algorithm will return -1 instead of 1.

And there are probably many other examples.

Have a nice day

Comment: Thanks, this is all I needed!

Comment: Super, but, could you edit the question in order to make it clearer. You can use the code I posted (by referring wikipedia). I'll remove mine and It will help the next people to have a quicker understanding of the question ;)

Comment: This is misleading / incorrect. If you change **only** `start <= end` to `start < end`, then yes, the algorithm will fail, but if you make appropriate code changes (see my answer) it will work just fine.

Answer (score 14):

For `low <= high`, `high` is considered **inclusive** (`high` is part of the range we consider).

For `low < high`, `high` is considered **exclusive** (`high` is not part of the range we consider).

Both can be correct, but there will be minor differences in the rest of the code, specifically how `high` is initialised (`high = length-1` versus `high = length`) and how it's updated (`high = mid-1` versus `high = mid`).

---

**Which one is better?**

The main difference is that `mid = (low + high) / 2` will be slightly different for each case.

More specifically, `high` will be 1 bigger in the exclusive case, thus, when `high-low` is even in the inclusive case, `mid` will stay the same, but when `high-low` is odd in the inclusive case, `mid` will be 1 element bigger in the exclusive case (this is because of rounding).

Let's consider an example:

```
length = 6
low = 0
highInclusive = 5, highExclusive = 6
midInclusive = 5/2 = 2, midExclusive = 6/2 = 3
```

As you can see, when there is no single middle element, one will pick the element to the left and the other will pick the element to the right.

While this will sometimes make the one faster and sometimes make the other faster, the average running time will be pretty much identical.

From a readability perspective, it might be slightly better (in my opinion) to use the exclusive one in languages with 0-based arrays and either one in languages with 1-based arrays, in order to minimise the number of `-1`'s in the code. An argument could also be made to just stick to a single version in all languages, as to not require that people understand both versions or get confused between the two.

Comment: Thank you. In some implementations, I saw they have `while (start + 1 < end)`, not sure why they added `+1` to `start` please?

Comment: @Avv I wouldn't be able to answer that off the top of my head without code, but if `start + 1 < end` implementations work, then something similar to what I said in the answer presumably applies: there would be other minor differences to make it work and there may be minor differences in terms of readability and/or performance. Although if it's `start + 1 <= end` instead, that would be equivalent to `start < end` (the difference between those is mostly just personal preference - I'd usually prefer the latter, although a `+1` can sometimes provide some insight into how exactly the code works).