# Binary search - moving the low & high indices

Tags: algorithm, search, binary-search

In the binary search implementations I see some versions use the condition `low < high` to terminate the loop and some use `low <= high`.

It looks like `low <= high` is used typically when the search is to look for a specific value.

`low < high` is used when implementing the discrete variant of the algorithm that applies a predicate, which is true or false in the search space and identify the inflection point (like go's Search
https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/sort/search.go#L9)

Is this interpretation correct and its required for the correctness of the algorithm ? I find it difficult to grasp the intuition behind when to use `<` vs `<=`

Comment: duplicate of e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35613574/when-to-use-in-binary-search-condition and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44231413/binary-search-using-start-end-vs-using-start-end

Answer (score 0):

It does not really matter.

If it is proper binary search, it has to work properly, no matter the implementation details.

Both is usable, the `low < high` can have one more step, but you dont care about it in complexity comparision. In real life scenarios, you dont care about it as well.